# Is it possible to send email attachments to a different address with PHP mail()?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

My company email does not have much space so I want to forward attachments to a Gmail address. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), works great.

Answer (score 0):

This [is possible](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). If you're running into issues with that, please post specific errors or questions!